# multi-thread communication structure

Tags: multi-threading

I know the basic cross-thread communication method, like pipe, socketpair. 
Is there any open source that implements the multi-thread communication structure so that I can integrate with my application quickly. One is dbus, but is seems complicated. So can you recommend?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a good look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) it is:

- Cross Platform
- Cross Language
- Fast
- Allows inter-process and inter-device communication
- Free, Gratis & Open Source